error when doing lm test for spatial autocorrelation in error terms

Below is an image of the data for some variables in pdata.frame format. The panel is for 166 municipalities in RN for 4 years, generating a total of 664 observations.Can I make the panel available on drive:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsPWGhkh95w3hIZpfVtH4OJ-x8f1xg?e=fuSJUb
the W matrix was created as follows using the SHP for the municipalities of RN.
nblist <- poly2nb(rn, queen = TRUE)
then I standardized it
w.rn.queen <- spdep::nb2listw(nblist, style="W")
when I try to perform the following test:
splm::slmtest(within_model,data = rn_df,listw = w.rn.queen,test='lme')
generates the error:
Error in X %*% coef(mod) : non-conformable arguments

Could you please provide the definition of your within_model? (i.e., please make sure to ask your question as a minimal reproducible example)

The error probably means that data structures that should have the same dimension(s) are of different dimensions.

The problem is the same in terms of dimension, but I don't know how to solve it. was defined as follows:   within_model <- plm(desp_cor_pcap ~ dcor_pcp_lg + area_pcap + pop_1_3 + pop_65 +                       perc_votos + lim_mandato + eleicao,                     data=rn_df, model = 'within',effect = 'twoways')
